# How to get a checkboxes value in JSP

Tags: html, mysql, jsp, checkbox

I have a kind of login page where the user enters in data and based on that data it runs an sql query but I also need to have check boxes so the user can tailor these queries a little more and select only stuff they require.

Is there any way of having a check box then checking what the value of that is on a later form? Will I be able to pass it the same way I pass text?

```
<jsp:forward page="somepage.jsp">
    <jsp:param name="empid" value="${(param.employeeid)}" />
    <jsp:param name="recorddate" value="${(param.date)}" />
    <jsp:param name="recorddate2" value="${(param.date2)}" />
</jsp:forward>
```

Also what data type does it pass am I after a boolean, string or integer?

Comment: Doesn't matter I've answered my own question. I passed the param through then ran a check to see if its not empty.